# How to access array values inside class object?

Tags: php, arrays, oop, object, scope

I have a array like this in a function:

```
$value = array("name"=>"test", "age"=>"00");
```

I made this $value as public inside the class abc.

Now in my other file, I want to access the values from this array, so I create an instance by:

```
$getValue = new <classname>;
$getValue->value..
```

I'm not sure how to proceed so that then I can access each element from that array.

Comment: Please post the actual class definition.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You mentioned that `$value` is in a function, but is public. Can you post the function, or clarify whether you meant declaring or instantiating within a function?

If you're instantiating it that's perfectly fine, and you can use the array keys to index `$value` just like any other array:

```
$object = new classname;
$name = $object->value["name"];
$age = $object->value["age"];

// Or you can use foreach, getting both key and value
foreach ($object->value as $key => $value) {
    echo $key . ": " . $value;
}
```

However, if you're talking about *declaring* `public $value` in a function then that's a syntax error.

Furthermore if you declare `$value` (within a function) *without* the `public` modifier then its [scope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_%28computer_science%29) is limited to that function and it cannot be `public`. The array will go out of scope at the end of the function and for all intents and purposes cease to exist.

If this part seems confusing I recommend reading up on [visibility in PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php).

Answer (score 2):

The same as you would normally use an array.

```
$getValue = new yourClass();
$getValue->value['name'];
```

Comment: He also said $value is a public variable inside his class, therefore accessible.

Comment: @Rob I get that, but he said **class** so therefore `class abc { public $var; $this->var['test'] = '1'; } $object = new abc(); echo $object->var['test']; //Outputs 1`

Comment: thanks to both of you. @rob, sorry I din't get you about editing the question and vote.

Answer (score 1):

Use code

```
foreach($getValue->value as $key=>$value)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php
        interface Nameable {
            public function getName($i);
            public function setName($a,$name);
        }
        class Book implements Nameable {
            private $name=array();
            public function getName($i) {
                return $this->name[$i];
            }
            public function setName($i, $name) {
                return $this->name[$i] = $name;
            }
        }

        $interfaces = class_implements('Book');

        if (isset($interfaces['Nameable'])) {
            $bk1 = new Book;
            $books = array('bk1', 'bk2', 'bk3', 'bk4', 'bk5');
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($books); $i++)
                $bk1->setName($i, $books[$i]);
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($books); $i++)
                echo '// Book implements Nameable: ' . $bk1->getName($i) . nl();
        }
?>
```